# Trying to calculate balance in Oracle Pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to calculate current stock which is less than or equal to entered date in pl/sql. For ex: I have 2 entries of debit  `100` and `20` on `1-jan-2015` and `5-jan-2015` respectively.then in my report it should show me balance `100 on 1-jan` and `120 on 5th of jan`.For that I am using loop within function.But it is not showing me the sum of stock.My code is:

```
V_NUM NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
IF(F_DR_CR='D')THEN 
 `IF C2%ISOPEN THEN 
   CLOSE C2;
  END IF;
  OPEN C2;
  FETCH C2 INTO V_BAL; 
  LOOP 
  V_NUM:=V_BAL+(V_NUM);
 RETURN V_NUM;
 EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Is there anyone who know the solution for my problem?

Comment: post the code of c2..

Comment: you can try running total in case it is 'D'.

Comment: we need to see the query of c2 cursor

Comment: It seems to me that your code will not run.  Instead I expect it will hurl `PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression`.   However, it is hard to be sure as you haven't posted the whole program.  RETURN doesn't do what you appear to think it does: certainly you are using it wrongly.  Again, without seeing your whole code it is difficult to correct your logic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to calculate a running total is with an Analytic SUM():

```
SQL> select dt
  2         , qty
  3         , sum (qty) over (order by dt) as run_tot
  4  from t23 
  5  order by dt
  6  /

DT               QTY    RUN_TOT
--------- ---------- ----------
07-JAN-15        100        100
13-JAN-15         20        120
19-JAN-15         20        140
25-JAN-15        -30        110

SQL>
```

No doubt somebody has said you must solve the problem with PL/SQL, but this is the simplest and most efficient approach.